# Refresh protected pivot-table with a button?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have this macro for a button to refresh all the pivot-tables in a worksheet:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

And I wanted to add the functionality to refresh all the pivot tables even if they are on a protected sheet. I protected the pivot-table sheet with the password MyPwd and used the below code, but it won't work:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Unprotect Password:="MyPwd"
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Protect Password:="MyPwd", _
DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
Scenarios:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End With
End Sub
```

Visual Basic is all new to me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @BK201 for having a crack at it, you definitely pointed me in the right direction. I used this code in the button and it seemed to do the trick:

```
Sub Button1_Click()


Dim Sht As Worksheet

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Sht.Unprotect Password:="MyPwd"
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Next

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Sht.Protect Password:="MyPwd"
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Unprotect` you want is a worksheet method. You should qualify it.

```
Sub ProtRef()
    Dim TargetSht As Worksheet
    Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as needed.

    With TargetSht
        .Unprotect MyPwd
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
        .Protect MyPwd
    End With
End Sub
```

Note `TargetSht` and the `With-End With`. Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

```
Sub ProtRef()

    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            WS.Unprotect MyPwd
        End If
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            WS.Protect MyPwd
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Paste in a regular module, like below:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I have multiple sheets with pivot-tables and the button is on a different sheet without pivot-tables. Do I right click on one of the pivot-table sheets, select view code, and enter this code? Or do I put it in the sheet with the button? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: What is the name of the unprotected sheet (the sheet without a pivot table and with the button)?

Comment: sheet1 and the pivot tables are on sheet3,sheet4,sheet5

Comment: See my edit above. If you don't want `Sheet2` to be protected as well, just do: `If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" And WS.Name <> "Sheet2" Then`. :)

Comment: I still cant get it to work. Here are three images of what I have [link](http://i.imgur.com/UBg0zSi.png)

Comment: Replace the contents of Button1_Click with the contents if the sub above. Just the contents. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help @BK201 but I keep getting a compile error? [image](http://i.imgur.com/j1uQRpj.png)

Comment: Oops, failed to qualify `Protect` and `Unprotect` myself, harhar. :D Glad you got it. :)